# How to find all users with the same User name\email address in Azure B2C using Azure Active Directory Graph Client?

Tags: c#, email, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, delete-row

The B2C Azure AD has users with the same e-mail address like 'someuser@gmail.com'.

```
User name                User type       Source                
someuser@gmail.com       Member          Azure Active Directory
someuser@gmail.com       Member          Microsoft Account
someuser@gmail.com       Member          Facebook
```

Note that what varies is the **Source** column. The email is the same.

Right now when I do a search like this:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/myb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6&$filter=signInNames/any(x:x/value%20eq%20%27someuser@gmail.com%27)
```

I get just one row: the one with source = Azure Active Directory but not the other 2 from external Identity Providers (IDPs).

How could I retrieve the 3 rows that match this User name\email address in one shot?

Once I get these 3 Users I'd like to delete them.

**####### EDIT #######**

From Chris Padget [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48657484/114029) I could get the users that have Facebook as issuer like this:

```
Get-User $filter=userIdentities/any(x:x/issuer%20eq%20%27facebook.com%27)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling with the [`$filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#filter) option, I got it working in a single shot like this:

```
Get-User $filter=signInNames/any(x:x/value%20eq%20%27someuser@gmail.com%27)%20or%20otherMails/any(y:y%20eq%20%27someuser@gmail.com%27)
```

For the external Identity Providers we need to check `otherMails` property.

#######

**Note:** it's necessary to encode the email address. I just tested this `$filter` using C# code with an email address like `someuser+1@gmail.com` and it was not retrieving the user. That's because of the `+` symbol.

We can use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(email)`.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4229054/114029).